# Where is gulp-useref.assets function defined

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm very new to gulp and node, so please excuse the newbie question. I'm trying to look at the source for the assets() function in the gulp-useref module, but I can't find it for the life of me. I can see the source code using toString(), but I don't see the wider context. Presumably, the following output from a VS "node.js interactive window" implies that the function is a property of the module, but I can't find it in the source on github:

```
> ur = require("gulp-useref");
{ [Function] assets: [Function] }
> ur
{ [Function] assets: [Function] }
> ur.hasOwnProperty("assets");
true
>
```

Where might it be getting this property? I see a local variable assets, but not a property. I'm assuming that whatever is going on here is more widely applicable than just gulp-useref?
Regards,
Marcus

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm looking at the index.js file on the github repo, but don't see an assets property.

Comment: OK, me being stupid. It looks like 2.1.0 of gulp-useref has an assets property. I was looking at 3.0.1. Now why my visual studio seems to be using 2.1.0 when I have 3.0.1 installed is odd, but that's another issue. :-)